# The area(in square units) bounded by the curves

Tags: calculus, geometry

The area (in square units) bounded by the curves $ y=x^{1/2} $ , $ 2y-x+3=0 $, x-axis and lying in the first quadrant is?

Comment: Please add more details, e.g. your working, etc.

Comment: What are your efforts? Did you at least find out the point of intersection? If so please mention it.

Comment: What do you know about finding areas bounded by curves? Where do you get stuck in applying it to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You have your curves $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\frac{x-3}{2}$. (Same as $2y-x+3=0$).
First, we find the points of intersection between both graphs to determine our bounds of integration.

We know that our lower bound for the integral will be $0$ since we are considering the 1st quadrant.

Next, we must find the intersection between the two curves.

$$\sqrt{x}=\frac{x-3}{2}$$
$$x=\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2 \tag{1}$$
$$4x=(x-3)^2$$
$$4x=x^2-6x+9$$
$$x^2-10x+9=0$$
This can be factorised as $(x-9)(x-1)=0$. Therefore, the intersection you are looking for is when $x=9$. This is our upper bound for the integral. Keep in mind that $x=1$ does not need to be considered since it is not a point of intersection. This is because we squared both sides on equation $(1)$, hence we cannot distinguish whether the solutions to $y$ are negative or positive without verification. If we substitute $x=1$ on both curves, we obtain different values of $y$, $y=1$ from the first curve and $y=-1$ from the second curve. Hence, $x=1$ is not an intersection point.

First evaluate:
$$\int_{0}^{9} \sqrt{x}~dx$$

Then evaluate:
$$\int_{3}^{9} \frac{x-3}{2}~dx$$
Note that for $y=\frac{x-3}{2}$, It is below the $x$-axis for $x<3$. Hence, this is why the bounds are from $3$ to $9$.

Therefore, the bounded area $A$ is given by:
$$A=\int_{0}^{9} \sqrt{x}~dx-\int_{3}^{9} \frac{x-3}{2}~dx$$
The integrals are subtracted to give the bounded area $A$ because the area under both curves is not bounded, and hence does not need to be considered.

These values work out to be:

$$A=\left[\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}\right]_0^9-\left[\frac{x^2-6x}{4}\right]_3^9=18-9=9$$

Hence, the area bounded by the two curves is $A=9$ square units.

Comment: Your bounds are very wrong. Between $0$ and $3$, $\frac{x-3}{2} \leq 0$. Also, those curves clearly don't intersect when $x=1$, you need to be careful about absolute values.

Comment: My apologies, I am changing my answer now.